# Beginner: How to get a fixed element to a left position (float left?) - JSFiddle included

Tags: html, css

My Problem is this

I have a big container 760px width which has a smaller container 700px with an article inside. Now I have social buttons in a 60px container to the left of the article. As people scroll down the container I want the social buttons to stay in place (so stay  in sight for the user). I tried this via. "position: fixed" BUT this moves my social buttons over to the left side. A workaround would be to give them a margin of like 700px to the left. But this might be a problem later on (and is not "nice").

I made a jsfiddle of the current state (without the fixed position)

**http://jsfiddle.net/MemCz/**

**The HTML**

```
<title>Artikel</title>


<body>

<div class="maincon">


    <div class="artikel"><h1>Amazon Fire TV review</h1><br>
    Amazon’s version of a media streamer is much like Apple’s or Roku’s: a basic black box that discreetly sits on my entertainment center. It’s a little larger and slightly thinner than the Apple TV or Roku 3, but that matters little — I just plugged the thing in and forgot about it. Aside from a small white LED on the front of the box to let me know it’s on, that’s it for alerts and design. The Fire TV isn’t expected to be a showpiece of my entertainment center, like a PlayStation 4 or Xbox One. It’s just supposed to blend into the background and do its job. Because really, this isn’t a story about hardware. This is about Amazon getting as many of its services as possible in to my living room.


Setting up the Fire TV is a breeze: once I plugged it in and put in my Wi-Fi password, it launched into a video tutorial demonstrating its many features (starring a bizarro normcore Doug Funnie character). As with its Kindle Fire tablets, Amazon preloaded my account on the Fire TV before it shipped it to me, so once the tutorial finished (you can’t skip it, I tried), all of my Amazon content was there right in front of me. Every TV show and movie I’d purchased from Instant Video, every photo I’d uploaded to Cloud Drive, all there for my consumption. (Starting next month, every song I upload to Amazon’s Cloud Player will be there too.)<br>

<h1>THE FIRE TV'S INTERFACE IS SUBDUED BUT EASY TO SEE AND CONTROL FROM THE COUCH</h1><br>
The interface will look familiar to anyone that’s used a Kindle Fire tablet: it’s a basic grid with categories on the left and content on the right. Unlike the Roku 3’s bright and colorful themes,  the Fire TV’s interface is mostly dark and understated. It’s easy to navigate and responsive thanks to the Fire TV’s powerful hardware, and most importantly, it’s easy to read from my couch. Needless to say, it’s a much better interface than anything a cable box has ever offered.

        <h1>THE FIRE TV'S INTERFACE IS SUBDUED BUT EASY TO SEE AND CONTROL FROM THE COUCH</h1><br>
The interface will look familiar to anyone that’s used a Kindle Fire tablet: it’s a basic grid with categories on the left and content on the right. Unlike the Roku 3’s bright and colorful themes,  the Fire TV’s interface is mostly dark and understated. It’s easy to navigate and responsive thanks to the Fire TV’s powerful hardware, and most importantly, it’s easy to read from my couch. Needless to say, it’s a much better interface than anything a cable box has ever offered.

</div>

<div class="social"> 
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/9PY48ir.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
<br>  
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/U4kusEr.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
<br>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q8JpVmS.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
</div><!-- end div social -->

</div>


</body>
```

**CSS**

```
    * {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }

.maincon {
    width:670px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;


}


.artikel {
    width:600px;
    float:left;
    padding:20px;

    font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro";
    font-size:12pt;
  }



img {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:right;
}

.head {
    width:660px;
    height: 60px;

}

.social {

    float:left;
    width:70px;
    height:400px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:50px;

}

h1 {
  font-family: "proxima-nova";
  }
```

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?
here is the fiddle with the fixed position failure going on: http://jsfiddle.net/MemCz/1/

Comment: Here is the fiddle with the "problem" (so with the fixed position)

http://jsfiddle.net/MemCz/1/

Comment: I'm interested in your version with position:fixed, but I think your link didn't work. Maybe you could edit it into the body of your question.

Comment: @user3744225 you have to still position your position:fixed; so that it's on the right.

Comment: @Katana314 ok done that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CSS `.social` class to the following:

```
.social {
    position:fixed;
    right:50px;
    width:70px;
    height:400px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

That'll make it work. You have position fixed, but with position fixed and absolute you can give it a distance from the edges of the screen. In this case, by using `right:50px;` you are telling the browser to render your social media buttons 50px from the right edge of the screen.

See updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vAL2y/

Comment: Ok but this will give me problems if i go responsive later on right? Because if the screen size is small the social icons will get pushed into the text right#?

Comment: You can put that within a container that is position:relative; and then position it from there, rather than from the edge of the screen. You'll of course need to use Media Queries to update its positioning and location as the screen size gets smaller. There is no "one style fits all" to cover all screen sizes.

Comment: everything is ok with you answer, give me a sec

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the float left and just need to add something like:

```
position:fixed;
right:5%;
```

in your container for the social media items. I'd recommend % over em or px;